# How can I run the code at google collab with GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I want to run a python file on Google collab with it's GPU,but it prints information below and dosn't run.  How can I figure out the reason for this problem?

```
!python3 "/content/drive/My Drive/train/avatar_train.py"
```

```
2019-04-13 02:10:42.624533: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2300000000 Hz
2019-04-13 02:10:42.624844: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x3002260 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-04-13 02:10:42.624886: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-04-13 02:10:42.687135: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-04-13 02:10:42.687674: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x3001fa0 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-04-13 02:10:42.687741: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2019-04-13 02:10:42.688116: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 10.89GiB
2019-04-13 02:10:42.688150: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-04-13 02:10:43.060618: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-04-13 02:10:43.060728: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 
2019-04-13 02:10:43.060761: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N 
2019-04-13 02:10:43.061106: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:42] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
2019-04-13 02:10:43.061184: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10542 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 3.7)
```

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem.